# Где и как в с++ зарезервированы слова left и right?

Tags: c++

Вот такой код, например, не вызовет ошибок

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  cout << left;
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/right/

Comment: сделай их переменными к примеру string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `<iomanip>` для форматирования вывода есть соответствующие манипуляторы.

Подробнее - [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left).

Типа

```
std::cout << "Left fill:\n" << std::left << std::setfill('*')
          << std::setw(12) << -1.23  << '\n'
          << std::setw(12) << std::hex << std::showbase << 42 << '\n'
          << std::setw(12) << std::put_money(123, true) << "\n\n";
```

дает

```
Left fill:
-1.23*******
0x2a********
USD *1.23***
```

Answer (score 4):

Они не "зарезервированы". Это идентификаторы, определенные в пространстве имен `std` в `<iomanip>`. Это, однако, не запрещает вам использовать эти имена для своих целей, т.е. ни о какой "зарезервированности" речи не идет.